# What equipment is best suited for pacing at my desk?

Tags: exercise-equipment, treadmill, elliptical

I've got a standing desk at work, and I like it a lot, but I often find that I don't really want to *stand*, I want to *pace*. But I can't pace while remaining at my desk. I'd like to fix that with some sort of treadmill or eliptical, but I'm not sure how to find something that meets my requirements.

My requirements (in order of importance):

1. Quiet. I have my own office, but the walls are thin and I don't want to disturb my coworkers.
2. User controlled speed. I'd like to be able to slow down, speed up, or stop at will, whatever matches my current focusing needs.
3. No/minimal electronics. My office can be... difficult about personal devices, and generally speaking the lower tech it is, the less problems I will have.
4. Easy to reposition.  My desk is variable height, so I can stand and sit, and I would still like the option of sitting with minimal difficulty if possible.

What sort of keywords and categories should I be looking for to get me what I need?